# Data compression techniques for power plant data

Tags: database, compression

I am studying about data management recently by myself. After reading some time, I still did not get the whole picture of how data is flowing from data acquisition to database or warehouse.

In power plant, I have 1000 sensors installed, so I want to know what happened before data is stored in database. For instance, from sensor data is sampled with 1Hz frequency, then with this big amount of data we need to do data compression, then send it to database I guess...So I want to know how those are all done, especially with the data compression, if the data are digital value with time stamp, what kind of data compression techniques can be used...and in Big Data concept, how data is compressed..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The people here would like to help you solve your issues. However you need to come with precise questions reflecting issues that you have faced. When the scope of your questions is too broad it makes it difficult to answer for there may be too many possible choices. Please take a look at this link about how to ask good questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The way OSIsoft PI does this is by checking how much a collected point has deviated from the previous point. If it is a small amount then the point gets "dropped" so only meaningful data is stored. When you ask for a value at a time in which no data exists. PI interpolates it.

Answer (score 1):

Data can be compressed in many ways, from zipping it up to totally custiomised solutions. In fact, for Power Plant data as you are looking at one of the larger systems is [PI from OSISOFT](http://www.osisoft.com/value/industry/PowerUtilities/). I used to work for a company who used them for 8 power stations. They have a totally bespoke database system where they store all their measurements. It is apparently optimised so that frequent readings from a sensor take up little space, and missing readings don't increase the space taken much. How they do it I have no idea - I expect it is proprietary and they won't tell people.

However, how data flows from sensor to database can be complex. Have a poke around the Osisoft site - they have some data available.

Comment: Thanks for the replying. Can you refer some popular data compression techniques ? I checked Delat- compression is one...thanks

Comment: Not personally. I only replied as I have knowledge (although second hand) of the type of system you're asking about.